# Weblogic Administration Console being blocked by browser - SSL server probably obsolete

Tags: ssl, weblogic, weblogic8.x

We are usng Weblogic 8.1 and administration console suddenly stopped and inaccessible today.

For more than a year we use to access it until today as it is being blocked by these browsers:

1. **Internet Explorer** - 
   There is a problem with this website's security certificate. When i click continue, it's not redirecting to the admin console.
2. **Google Chrome** - SSL server probably obsolete. 
   ERR_SSL_FALLBACK_BEYOND_MINIMUM_VERSION
3. **Firefox** - Secure Connection Failed
   An error occurred during a connection to 192.168.0.18:17050. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

Comment: This is probably still Java 5 right ? 
I think WL 10 still requires Java 5 as I recall. 
First try upgrade your Java version to the latest you can get working with 8.1.

Comment: You can also try install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength for your Java version.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-419418.html#jce_policy-1.5.0-oth-JPR

Comment: We are using the jrockit built in runtime from weblogic 8.1, this is equivalent to java 1.4. We can't instantly migrate the system to a higher runtime version as it is already in production. This is actually a legacy framework btw.

Comment: can you try install the JCE Unlimited Strength for JRocket ? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13205_01/wcp/wng10/userguide/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

You are running a very old version of JRocket Java equivalent to 1.4.
There is a SSL protocol mismatch between your modern browsers and Weblogic's JRocket.

My best guess is to install the [JRocket Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13205_01/wcp/wng10/userguide/installation.html) into your JRocket to boost the cipher list.

[nmap](https://nmap.org/) has a [ssl-enum-ciphers](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html) that will be able to print out the list of ciphers avialable before and after you install the Unlimited Strength files. See [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative and very ugly solution in Firefox.

Try [this](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH87649).

Enable support for 40-bit RSA encryption in the Firefox Browser:

- enter 'about:config' in Browser Address bar
- find/select
- "security.ssl3.rsa_rc4_40_md5" set boolean to TRUE

Or [this](https://lotusbay.wordpress.com/2015/02/04/resolving-ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap-in-firefox/).

- Open a new tab in Firefox and type “about:config” in the URL bar
- You would get a warning dialog box, click Promise to be careful and move on
- In the search bar, enter the following security.tls.version
- First, right-click on the setting “security.tls.version.fallback-limit” and select modify.  You’re going to change the “1” to “0”.  Then do the same thing with “security.tls.version.min”, changing the “1” to “0”.